# Undefined function 'preview' for input arguments of type 'struct'

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Hai I am using Back round subtraction method on frame.Now I want to see the preview of these frames.But Error is occured " **Undefined function 'preview' for input arguments of type 'struct'**. This is code:

```
for i = 2:numFrames

  %fr = vid(i).cdata;
  % read in frame 
  fr= read(vid, i);

  fr_bw = rgb2gray(fr);       % convert frame to grayscale 
  fr_diff = abs(double(fr_bw) - double(bg_bw));  % cast operands as double to avoid negative overflow 
  threshHold=mean(fr_diff);%Experimetn
  for j=1:width                 % if fr_diff > thresh pixel in foreground 
      for k=1:height 
          if ((fr_diff(k,j) > threshHold)) 
              fg(k,j) = fr_bw(k,j); 
          else 
              fg(k,j) = 0; 
          end 
      end 
  end
  bg_bw = fr_bw; %store old frame to bg_bw variable

  imshow(fr_bw);
  figure(1),subplot(3,1,1),imshow(fr) 
  subplot(3,1,2),imshow(fr_bw) 
  subplot(3,1,3),imshow(uint8(fg)) ;
  z=i-1;

  q(z) = im2frame(uint8(fg),gray(256));            % put frames into movie
  preview((q(z))); 

end
```

Comment: Where do you define `q` as a video object?

Comment: This is not the purpose of [`preview`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/preview.html). You probably want to use [`movie`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html)

Comment: This is happening because q(z) is a structure. Use the cdata of q(z) to access the image. Try preview(q(z).cdata)

Comment: user3288586 this not work

Comment: @BillBokeey  q is consist frame